# How do you import json files into a node js file when pushing to AWS Amplify

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a file that creates an account in AWS cognito:

```
const { Amplify } = require('aws-amplify');
const { signUp } = require('aws-amplify/auth');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function doSomething() {
try {
  const pathToAmplifyConfig = path.join("/Users", "myusername", "Desktop", "testingamplify", "backend", "src", "amplifyconfiguration.json");
  const amplifyConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathToAmplifyConfig, 'utf8'));

  Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
  const { isSignUpComplete, userId, nextStep } = await signUp({
    username: "mytestusername123",
    password: "mypassword",
    options: {
      userAttributes: {
        email: "mytestemail@gmail.com",
      },
      // optional
      autoSignIn: true // or SignInOptions e.g { authFlowType: "USER_SRP_AUTH" }
    }
  });
  console.log("User created!");

  // console.log(userId);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('there was an error when singing:', error);
}
}
doSomething();
```

when I run this file locally it works great. But when I run "Amplify Push" in the terminal and upload to AWS this file no longer works. Instead it gives me an error:  "Cannot find module /Users/myusername/Desktop/testingamplify/backend/src/amplifyconfiguration.json".

How do I correctly import amplifyconfiguration.json into this file so I can use it in AWS cloud? This function is a simple lambda function that is uploaded to API Gateway so when I make a call to an HTTP request it executes this lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The file location is based on your system location that starts with `/Users..`. This path won't be found while building. You should try to read the path relative to the file that is using it.

```
const pathToAmplifyConfig = path.resolve(__dirname, "<relative path from your file that is reading the json config>")
```

`__dirname` will be the path till your file.